# Streamwriter: write two listboxes on the same row

Tags: vb.net, listbox, streamwriter

I am trying to write, in order to export on txt file, information in two listbox with the same number of rows. I have to export them with the following format: `Listbox1, Listbox2.` In order to do this, I've tried to use the following code:

```vb
Using writer = New StreamWriter(SaveFileDialog1.FileName)
    For Each o As Object In Form3.ListBox1.Items And Form3.ListBox2.Items
        writer.WriteLine(o)
    Next
End Using
```

I'm receiving the following error:

> BC30452    Operator 'And' is not defined for types 'ListBox.ObjectCollection' and 'ListBox.ObjectCollection'.

I've also tried to perform three `For Each loops`, the first for the LB1, the second for the commas and the third for LB2, but I'm having it exported with content on single lines. How could I solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the error message says, the syntax you attempted is simply not valid. There's no feature in VB.NET that does that sort of thing.

However, the .NET Framework API does provide a means for something similar, which would probably work in your case. See [`Enumerable.Zip()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.zip). You can use it like this:

```vb
Using writer = New StreamWriter(SaveFileDialog1.FileName)
    For Each o As String In Form3.ListBox1.Items.Cast(Of Object).Zip(Form3.ListBox2.Items.Cast(Of Object), Function(x1, x2) x1 & ", " & x2)
        writer.WriteLine(o)
    Next
End Using
```

Answer (score 1):

If you use `Enumerable.Zip`, as suggested in another answer, then you can make the code more succinct by doing away with the explicit loop:

```vb
File.WriteAllLines(SaveFileDialog1.FileName,
                   Form3.ListBox1.
                         Items.
                         Cast(Of Object).
                         Zip(Form3.ListBox2.
                                   Items.
                                   Cast(Of Object),
                             Function(x1, x2) $"{x1}, {x2}"))
```

If you didn't use `Zip` then you can use a loop this way:

```vb
Dim items1 = Form3.ListBox1.Items
Dim items2 = Form3.ListBox2.Items

Using writer = New StreamWriter(SaveFileDialog1.FileName)
    For i = 0 To Math.Min(items1.Count, items2.Count)
        writer.WriteLine($"{items1(i)}, {items2(i)}")
    Next
End Using
```

The `Math.Min` part is just in case there are different numbers of items in each `ListBox`. If you know there aren't then you can do away with that and just use one `Count`. If there might be different counts but you want to output all items then the code would become slightly more complex to handle that.

Answer (score 0):

Since you said that both list boxes have the same number of items we can use the number of items in the first listbox less one (indexes start at zero) in a `For` loop.

I used a `StringBuilder` so the code does not have to throw away and create a new string on each iteration.

I used an interpolated string indicate by the `$` preceding the string. This means I can insert variables in braces, right along with literals.

Call `.ToString` on the `StringBuilder` to write to the text file.

```
Private Sub SaveListBoxes()
    Dim sb As New StringBuilder
    For i = 0 To ListBox1.Items.Count - 1
        sb.AppendLine($"{ListBox1.Items(i)}, {ListBox2.Items(i)}")
    Next
    File.WriteAllText("C:\Users\xxx\Desktop\ListBoxText.txt", sb.ToString)
End Sub
```